# How to run grunt commands in git-bash using java class program and display in console

Tags: shell, automation, gruntjs, git-bash, grunt-contrib-watch

I need to open to run grunt task runner and Git commands from this class file, but am not sure how to pass the commands.I tried all those specified on the web but they only workout for cmd.Also i can't understand all those /k and /c those tags.where can i find all those refereances.
1.Change Directory 
2.run grunt task -(grunt , grunt watch...)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Cmdtesttwo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git- 
bash.exe"," grunt");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = builder.start();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while (true) {
line = r.readLine();
     if (line == null) { break; }
     System.out.println(line);
 }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like below, here your command/program output will be printed in a output.txt file. Do not forget to create log folder:-

```
String[] command ={"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe", "grunt"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.redirectOutput(new File("C:\\log\\output.txt"));
try {
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();       

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It actually returns access is denied.

Comment: Your program does not have access to C:\\Program Files\\Git\\ you need to provide proper access to the exe file.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Hi, try with my modified answer. Try with my last option in my answer. Let me know the output.

Comment: Tried with the modified way - Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe  grunt": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: grunt specified is a command but the error shows that the file can't be found.!!!

Comment: I have modified my answer. It will work now. Try and let me know.

Comment: Is it work if you run `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe  grunt` in command prompt?

Comment: i tried for git-bash but this is what it returns - CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation . But i tried for git-cmd.exe and it was working. How to solve this error=740 elevation issue? I have even changed the compatibility of git-bash to always run as administrator from the compatibility in properties.

Comment: run your java program as administrator.